# Understanding python nested one line for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to understand one line for-loops and putting it in to normal nomenclature for nested for-loops. The one-liner for-loops is as follows:

```
print ''.join((letter[i - 1]for i in (int(n) for n in key.split())))
```

I wrote the above nested for-loops in a conventional way as follows:

```
for n in key.split():
    n = int(n)
    for i in n:
        print ''.join(letter[i - 1])
```

I am not getting the desired result. Please can someone explain where my thinking is going wrong or how can the above one-line for-loops can be written conventionally. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those are *list comprehensions*, not "loops". Searching for the keyword will provide much reading on how they work..

Comment: What are you trying to do with `for i in n` where `n` is an `int`? An `int` object is not iterable

Comment: Those are generator expressions, not list comprehensions

Comment: @first commenter list comprehensions and loops are not mutually exclusive, furthermore, those aren't list comprehensions...As cababunga has noted, they're generator expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look carefully at the parentheses in your one-liner:

```
print ''.join((letter[i - 1]for i in (int(n) for n in key.split())))
                                     ^---------------------------^
```

The nested generator is simply a sequence that provides values for the outer generator. It could be simplified to

```
print ''.join((letter[int(i) - 1]for i in (n for n in key.split())))
```

or just

```
print ''.join(letter[int(i) - 1] for i in key.split())
```

An equivalent loop would be

```
for i in key.split():
    print letter[int(i) - 1],    # Suppress the newline
```

Comment: Thank you @chepner..But everytime I print with your line, I am getting a space after every letter. How can I remove that? Thanks.

Comment: Ugh, that's a good question. I don't remember if there is a way with the print *statement*; either add `from __future__ import print_function` to the top of your script so you can use `print(letter[int(i) - 1], end='')`, or use the version that uses `''.join` use `print` only once.

Answer (score 1):

Example of nested loops simplification.

```
from enum import IntEnum

class MyEnum(IntEnum):
    FOO_BAR = 0
    JOHN_DOE = 1
    
result = []
for x in MyEnum:
    x_splits = []
    for s in x.name.split('_'):
        x_splits.append( s.capitalize() )    
    result.append ( ' '.join(x_splits) )
    
# >>> result
# ['Foo Bar', 'John Doe']
```

First step:

```
result = []
for x in MyEnum:
    x_splits = [ s.capitalize() for s in x.name.split('_') ]
    result.append ( ' '.join(x_splits) )
```

Second step:

```
result = []
for x in MyEnum:
    result.append ( ' '.join( s.capitalize() for s in x.name.split('_') ) )
```

Third step:

```
result = [ ' '.join( s.capitalize() for s in x.name.split('_') ) for x in MyEnum ]
```

result the same:

```
# ['Foo Bar', 'John Doe']
```